# How to pass node module defined express routes to main index.js file

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

Say for example in my `node_module` folder I have an npm called `project` which has some set defined express routes. For example,

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('indexPage', {title: 'Homepage'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

which is kept in a `routes.js` file

How would this be accessed in the main node project file `index.js` file?

I have attempted to use `require()` function, however, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set your app as an Express app then add your routes middleware(s) like the below.

Also I've added some useful code parts (a simple Express app) for any beginner:

```
// defining an express app
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var server = require('http').Server(app)


// setting the express app - in case of needed
app.set('x-powered-by', false) // hide x-powered-by header!
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set EJS as view engine!
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); // specifying the directory that contains view files

// THIS IS YOUR ANSWER PART
app.use(require('./routes'))
... 
... 
// Other middlewares
app.use(require('./middlewares/someMiddleware'))
// Catching 404 errors
app.use('*', function(req,res){
    res.status(404).send("URL not found.")
})
// Catching and evaluating the other errors 
app.use(require("./middlewares/errorHandler"))

server.listen(3001, function() {
    console.log('APP Server is listening HTTP port 3001')
})
```

Generally the last route is been 404 error. So, if the request has not been caught in any route before 404, that means "the page cannot found".

Also, errorHandler middleware takes 4 arguments (error, request, response and next).

So, if you encountered with an error in your `routes.js`, and if you send this error in `routes` files by using `next(err)` this error can be caught on `errorHandler` middleware.

This is basic information which everyone needs when starting to develope an Express application.

For more details: 
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Good luck...

Comment: Thanks, for the useful guide too

Comment: @RH7, I've edited my answer. It might be useful for you.